# How to update status on pretty table in python?

Tags: python, prettytable

I am using python pretty table to print the status of each record on CLI. 
How to display the status updates on the CLI in the same table.

```
Example:

+--------------+---------+
| Jobs         |  Status |
+--------------+---------+
|  job1        |  FAILED |
|  job2        | SUCCESS |
+--------------+---------+
```

The jobs status will be updated by a thread. I want to display the updated status in the same table in CLI console.

Comment: Can you add some code? What have you tried? Maybe add an example of the output you want, so we can understand what you want better

Comment: You'll need to use some sort of terminal control library like [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), or a higher-level console UI framework like [`urwid`](http://urwid.org/).

Comment: I need to display this table just like the way the display for progress bar

Answer (score 0):

I found ascii code to move the cursor to the previous line. And I am using the below logic to achieve the purpose

```
number_of_records = len(records)  # number of jobs in a tables
total_lines = number_of_records + 3 + 1 # number of records + Borders + Header

if prev_lines != 0:
   for i in range(prev_lines):
      sys.stdout.write('\033[F')

prev_lines = total_lines

print status_table
```

Thanks :)